# How do I make it so that my dark mode works when fullscreen is on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a counter (i know it is really simple) with JS, and I recently added a dark mode to it. Then, I realized that I also needed to add a fullscreen to it. But, when it is in fullscreen mode, my dark mode does not work. I tried searching it up on google but I couldn't find anything. Can y'all look at my code and try to tell me what is wrong or what I should add?

Here is JS:

```
var name = prompt("What do you want to name your counter?");
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Counter: " + name;

function maxWindow() {
    var isInFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);

    var page = document.getElementById("page");

    if (!isInFullScreen) {
        if (page.requestFullscreen) {
            page.requestFullscreen();
            document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").innerHTML = "Exit Fullscreen";
            document.getElementById("page").style.background = "white";
        } else if (page.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            page.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (page.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            page.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (page.msRequestFullscreen) {
            page.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
            document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").innerHTML = "Fullscreen";
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}

function increment() {
    var number = document.getElementById("counterAmount").value;
    number = +number + +1;
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").value = number;
}

function decrement() {
    var number = document.getElementById("counterAmount").value;
    number = +number - +1;
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").value = number;
}

function reset() {
    var number = document.getElementById("counterAmount").value;
    number = 0;
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").value = number;
}

function dark() {
    document.body.style.background = "#566880";

    document.getElementById("header").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("counter").style.background = "#1e2931";
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").style.background = "#566880";
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").style.color = "black";

    document.getElementById("arrow-up").style.borderBottom = "20px solid #566880";
    document.getElementById("arrow-down").style.borderTop = "20px solid #566880";

    document.getElementById("button").style.background = "#566880";
    document.getElementById("buttonreset").style.background = "#566880";
    document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").style.background = "#566880";
    document.getElementById("button").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("buttonreset").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = light;
}

function light() {

    document.body.style.background = "white";

    document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#545454";

    document.getElementById("counter").style.background = "#d7dfe7";
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").style.background = "white";
    document.getElementById("counterAmount").style.color = "gray";


    document.getElementById("arrow-up").style.borderBottom = "20px solid gray";
    document.getElementById("arrow-down").style.borderTop = "20px solid gray";
    document.getElementById("arrow-down").style.borderLeft = "20px solid transparent";
    document.getElementById("arrow-down").style.borderRight = "20px solid transparent";


    document.getElementById("button").style.background = "white";
    document.getElementById("buttonreset").style.background = "white";
    document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").style.background = "white";
    document.getElementById("button").style.color = "#545454";
    document.getElementById("buttonreset").style.color = "#545454";
    document.getElementById("buttonfulscrn").style.color = "#545454";
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = dark;

}
```

and here is HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Covered+By+Your+Grace" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div id = "page" class="page">
  <br>
  <title id="title"></title>
  <header>
    <h1 id = "header"></h1>
  </header>
  <br>
  <div class="counter" id="counter">
    <div class="arrow-up" id="arrow-up"onclick="increment()"></div>
    <input id = "counterAmount" disabled="disabled" value="0">
    <div class="arrow-down" id="arrow-down" onclick="decrement()"></div>
    <button onclick="reset()" id="buttonreset"> Reset </button><br><br>
    <button onclick="dark()" id="button"> Dark mode </button><br><br>
    <button onclick="maxWindow()" id="buttonfulscrn"> Fullscreen </button><br><br>
  </div>  

</div>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you turn into dark mode with fullscreen mode disable : that's the "body" element that switch color into dark. But with fullscreen mode enable : that's the "div" element identified by id "#page" that have to be switch.

You can try to add this line to your dark() function :

```
document.getElementById("page").style.background = "black";
```

And also do the opposite in your light() function like :

```
document.getElementById("page").style.background = "white";
```

I recommend you to press F12 in your web browser to open the html/css code editor and you will see easily which elements required to be set to dark, or not.

Comment: I did that, I'm pretty sure. And, I have a Chromebook so I don't have an "f12" key

Comment: Did you try it ? It work on my side. And no problem, F12 is just a shortcut, you probably have a option when you right click on any web page that allow you to open the code inspector. On firefox, it's something like "Inspect Element". If you got another web browser, you can check this tutorial https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549.